# Understanding to get mean from integer stream using heap

Tags: python, algorithm, heap

I am following the below blog and understood how to get the median in a very subtle way. The blog is [here](http://www.ardendertat.com/2011/11/03/programming-interview-questions-13-median-of-integer-stream/)

Now, I added the below function to the streamMedian class to get the mean of the number inserted and not getting the desired output

```
import heapq

class streamMedian:
    def __init__(self):
        self.minHeap, self.maxHeap = [], []
        self.N=0


    def insert(self, num):
        if self.N%2==0:
            heapq.heappush(self.maxHeap, -1*num)
            self.N+=1
            if len(self.minHeap)==0:
                return
            if -1*self.maxHeap[0]>self.minHeap[0]:
                toMin=-1*heapq.heappop(self.maxHeap)
                toMax=heapq.heappop(self.minHeap)
                heapq.heappush(self.maxHeap, -1*toMax)
                heapq.heappush(self.minHeap, toMin)
        else:
            toMin=-1*heapq.heappushpop(self.maxHeap, -1*num)
            heapq.heappush(self.minHeap, toMin)
            self.N+=1

    def getMedian(self):
        if self.N%2==0:
            return (-1*self.maxHeap[0]+self.minHeap[0])/2.0
        else:
            return -1*self.maxHeap[0]

    def getMean(self):
        sum = 0
        for num in self.maxHeap:
            sum += num
        for num in self.minHeap:
            sum += num 
        return sum/self.N
```

This is the function call to the streamMedian class.

```
test = streamMedian()
test.insert(1)
test.insert(2)
test.insert(3)
print test.getMedian()
print test.getMean()
```

The median here should be 2 and mean should be 2 (Instead 0 is the output). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `mean` should be `(1+2+3)/3 == 2`.

Comment: Edited. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing negative numbers to your `maxHeap` (`-1*num`).
You need to reverse that in your `getMean()`, e.g.:

```
def getMean(self):
    total = 0
    for num in self.maxHeap:
        total -= num
    for num in self.minHeap:
        total += num 
    return total/self.N
```

Or alternatively:

```
def getMean(self):
    return (abs(sum(self.maxHeap)) + sum(self.minHeap))/self.N
```

*Note: don't use `sum` as a variable it hides the python builtin `sum()` function.*

Answer (score 1):

AChampion's answer correctly identifies the issue with your current code and offers a reasonable fix while still using your current algorithm. However, that algorithm is not very efficient (it takes `O(N)` time) and you can do better.

Specifically, you should add the value you're inserting to a cumulative sum in addition to pushing it onto one of your heaps. That way, when you need to get a mean, you can compute it in constant time (with just a single division):

```
class streamMedian:
    def __init__(self):
        self.minHeap, self.maxHeap = [], []
        self.cumulative_sum = 0.0             # new instance variable
        self.N=0


    def insert(self, num):
        self.cumulative_sum += num            # add each value to it
        # rest of insert code...

    # median code...

    def getMean(self):
        return self.cumulative_sum / self.N   # compute the mean in constant time
```

Note that if you're using Python 2 (which it appears you are) it's important that `cumulative_sum` is initialized with the float value `0.0` instead of the integer `0` (which would otherwise be natural). When you divide two integers in Python 2, you'll get another integer, rounding down. That may not be desirable if you're computing, say, the mean of `1` and `2` (you'd expect `1.5`, but you'd get `1` if you just do `(1 + 2) / 2`). Python 3 does this better (you always get a float from regular division and can use the `//` operator to explicitly request "floor" division). If you want to get the same semantics in Python 2, you can put `from __future__ import division` at the top of your module.

Comment: Isn't this still `O(n)` just spread out over every insert - as in you are still doing a `+=` operation for every item which is `O(n)`. The difference this is `O(n)` once vs. `O(n)` every call to `getMean()`.

Comment: I was assuming you'd want to call `getMean` many times (or there would be no point in using a streaming calculation). If you call `getMean` `O(n)` times, then the cost of adding up the values gets amortized out to `O(1)` per call.